# Exclude a pattern from grep result

Tags: unix, grep

I use below command to search for a specific text in a directory and its sub-directories.

**`find . -exec grep -i -n -w 'search text' /dev/null {} \;`**

Result is displayed in below format
**`./directory/filename:<line_number>:<matching text>`**

I want to exclude all lines with **`/*`** from the result.

How to do this?

**OS Version:** Sun OS 5.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe the result through `grep` again, filtering *out* matches of `/*`:

```
find . -exec grep -i -n -w 'search text' /dev/null {} \; | grep -v '/\*'
```

where `grep -v` returns lines that *don't* match (and I'm assuming you mean a literal `/*` hence the regex).

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks. Yes, i want to exclude literal `/*`

Answer (score 0):

pipe the whole thing through grep -v 'exclude pattern'